# MS CRM: Can I create a custom activity partylist?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, custom-activity

I'm creating a new activity type for text messages and I would like to customize the 'To' field with a custom partylist. IE the lookup field that can be either an account, lead, contact or user. I want to remove accounts and users and limit the partylist to allow only leads and contacts in the To field for this activity.

Is there any supported or unsupported methods for accomplishing this?

Comment: I don't think you can create the custom partylist.
You can create a "To" control use silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know only unsupported: http://rajeevpentyala.wordpress.com/2012/08/02/filtering-partylist-entities-using-jscript-in-crm/

Comment: Unfortunately with the recent roll up release, that solution will no longer work for anyone who upgrades so it's not an option. Thanks though. =(

Comment: It would probably still work if the users where just using IE. Though I dont know that for sure.

Comment: We were using crmform for another purpose and worked with MS to find another solution because this update completely removed it to enable the cross browser compatibility. AFAIK, it's gone for good. Either way we need to support Chrome and Firefox as well.